# Send email on submit with AJAX is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to send an email when a button has been clicked. The button is created with bootstrap 5. Jquery will then send an AJAX request to a php file which should send the email. But it looks like the requested email.php file is not called. No code in that file is executed, no exit.In the console I got the success message from ajax and 'Button 2 clicked'. I have checked several posts. What is wrong? Please see below code.

form.php

```
            <div class="text-center mt-4 mb-4 ftp-order">
            <button type="submit" name="ftp-submit" id="ftp-submit" class="btn btn-success"><?php echo $arr_lang['bestellen']; ?></button>
        </div>
```

main.js

```
    $('#ftp-submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Button clicked");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'dateien/ajax/premium_account.php',
            data: '{pressed:pressed}',
            datatype: 'JSON',
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Button clicked 2");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert('There was some error');
                console.log(error);
            },
        });
    $('#ftp-alert').css("display", "block");
    return false;
});
```

email.php

```
    $sender = "sender@example.com";

if(mail('info@example.com', 'FTP', 'Test', $sender)) {
    echo 'sent mail';
    exit('exit1');
} else {
    echo 'error sending email';
    exit('exit2');
}

if (isset($_POST)) {
    exit('exit');
    ?>
    <script>console.log("received")</script>
<?php
}

?>

<div id="test"></div>
<script>console.log("received")</script>
```

Comment: Try changing `data: '{pressed:pressed}',` to `data: {pressed: 'pressed'},`. If you're quoting the object, you'll send it as a string, not as post params.

Comment: Use ``if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") { //Your email code goes here } ``  This will make sure only POST request are accepted, and ``data: '{pressed:pressed}' ``, to ``data: {pressed: 'pressed'}``

Comment: Also, `exit()` immediately terminates the execution of the script, so if you have any `echo` (or any code) after that, it won't be executed. Your `if (isset($_POST)) {` will also never be executed since you have and `if/else` where both states contains `exit`

Comment: You should also [read the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) for `mail()` to see how to properly add the sender address.

Comment: Your AJAX calls `dateien/ajax/premium_account.php` and you show `email.php`, how are they related? Also, if you don't actually _submit_ a form you can change your button to a "regular" button (`type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`) and remove `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have changed it. Probably I don't need data, as I don't want to send any data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your mail server it must be configured properly to mail() function be workable.